# How to change the value of an Observable of Object Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, observable

how can i change a single property of an Observable of an Object Array. In my service im doing an http request to get all Tasks:

```
getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Task[]>('http://localhost:8080/tasks');
}
```

This is my Task Interface:

```
export interface Task {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  dueDate: Date;
  taskstatus: TaskStatus;
  user: User;
}
```

The Problem is, the dueDate of the Respone Object of the http Request ist just a string, although I defined it in the database as Timestamp, i just get a timestamp as string like
"2021-09-25T11:36:29.000+00:00".

Now my question is how can i change the value inside the Observible something like:
task.dueDate = new Date(task.dueDate)
so that i can transform all date strings into actual Date types. (for all Objects of the Array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `map` operator is used for data transforms on observables, and you'll use the array `map` inside of the rx `map` to transform each object in the array:

```
getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Task[]>('http://localhost:8080/tasks').pipe(
    map(tasks => tasks.map(task => {
      // do whatever to the task
      task.dueDate = new Date(task.dueDate);
      return task;
    }))
  );
}
```

you might need to fiddle with your typings to make it compile though.